# Unorderd list columns in body & footer

Tags: html, css, html-lists, footer, document-body

How to stop ul columns in body affecting my footer ul?
I've got 'ul' with 'li's in body and I gave them 3 columns in CSS:

```
ul {
    overflow: hidden;
    live-style:none;
    margin-top: 70px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    columns: 3;
  -webkit-columns: 3;
  -moz-columns: 3;
}
```

I've also got 'ul' in my footer. But I want it to be inline. For some reason my 4 Footer buttons are grouped in 2 and follow 3 column pattern.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use a selector than only applies to `ul` in the `footer` to adjust the styling there

```
footer ul {

 /* your styles here */

}
```

Comment: I've tried that and all other possible combinations with class. Still the same: when the screen is small my 4 footer buttons group in 2, following 2 columns above, when the screen is fully open all 4 buttons go under 1st column. @Paulie_D